# unable to get data from api controller js file to view ejs file in sails js with Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, sails.js

I am working on Sails (latest version 1.x)  with Vue.js application, and in  my `names.page.js`, I have

`data: { names : [], //… }`,

```
beforeMount: function() { 
// Attach any initial data from the server.
 _.extend(this, SAILS_LOCALS);
 this.names = [{id: 1, name: 'abc'}, {id:2, name: 'xyz'}]
 },
```

Which I could able to successfully get in `names.ejs` and display the names array of objects.

```
<pre>{{names}}</pre>
```

Now I have removed the `this.names = [{id: 1, name: 'abc'}, {id:2, name: 'xyz'}]` code from  `names.page.js` and moved to `view-names.js`,  and is as shown below:

```
 fn: async function () {
    var sampleNames = [{id: 1, name: ‘abc’}, {id:2, name: ‘xyz’}]
    // Respond with view.
    return {
    names : sampleNames
    }

    }
```

but in my names.ejs when I give `<pre>{{names}}</pre>`, I am getting output as empty array `[]`, the actual names data ( array of objects) is not getting displayed. Can any one help me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

view-names.js seems like an action so it doesn't send data to the ejs template directly.

You have to use the names.page.js which is the page instance for the names.ejs view.

You can work with the sampleNames in the action then send the result to a names.page.ejs variable which in turn is accessible from within the view names.ejs

Sure,

Build your variable first and send it to the page instance

view-names.js:
`names = [{id: 1, name: 'abc'}, {id:2, name: 'xyz'}]
return {
mynames: names
}`

names.page.js (page instance)
You have the variable set in the data
`data: {
   mynames: {}
}`

names gets populate from the action view-names.js

Now you can work with it in the view, like for example in a v-for loop

`<ul v-for="name in names">
  <li>{{ name }}</li>
</ul>`

Comment: can you please provide some sample code how to do that? I made the changes as put up in my question,   based on the references I have got but those are not working.

Comment: corrected the misspelled mynames instead of the names in the page instance data

Comment: i think in .ejs file it should be mynames instead names

Comment: yes, it does, that is why I have corrected my answer yesterday; misspelled it due to the typing speed :-(